# Counting with restrictions.

Tags: combinatorics

I need help with counting with restrictions, such as in the problem

In how many ways can we distribute 13 pieces of identical candy to 5 kids, if the two youngest kids are twins and insist on receiving an equal number of pieces?

How do you complete these type of questions?

NOTE:  This is NOT the exact question, mine has more people.

Any help is appreciated.

-Annie

Comment: It'd be useful if you told us how much you know about combinatorics.

Comment: I know about permutations and combinations...

Comment: In your problem, how many candies? For smallish like $13$ we can do cases and Stars and Bars for each case.

Comment: You mean in my real question I have to answer?  For that I have to do 20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have $n$ candies, and $c$ kids. You can first select how many candies you want to give the twins, suppose it is $2r$ in total. Then there are $c-2$ kids and $n-2r$ candies left. You can now give these candies away freely. We use the method of [stars and bars](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/603582/17-varieties-of-donuts-order-12-donuts-variety-repetition-allowed-12-of-each/603590#603590) to count the number of ways: there are $n-2r$ candies(stars) and there are $c-2$ kids left which need $c-3$ bars to be separated, then there are $\binom{n-2r+c-3}{c-3}$ ways to distribute the candies.

Since $r$ can go anywhere from $0$ to $\frac{n}{2}$ the final answer is:

$\sum\limits_{r=0}^\frac{n}{2}\binom{n-2r+c-3}{c-3}$

---

In your particular question $n=13,c=5$. Hence the answer is

$\sum\limits_{r=0}^2\binom{n-2r+c-3}{c-3}=\binom{15}{2}+\binom{13}{2}+\binom{11}{2}=238$

Comment: Thank you for explaining that very clearly!

Comment: Sure, my pleasure, I hope it helped. I am glad to answer any further questions.